# Data partition with known partition sizes

Tags: database, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, partitioning

I got dataset that contains 5555 sentences. I know that this sentences can be partitioned into 3 groups with sizes: 10, 300, 5245. My goal is to find group of sentences with size of 10 and 300. The sentences were generated by chat GPT with condition that stated each cluster should have similar ones.

Im pretty new to ML, i know basics of NLP and know how organise data to apply ML model. I need to know which algotithm would be best for this type of problem. I was thinking about k-means, but with the information about cluster sizes and disproportion of them i think it would be insufficient and there should be better method. Does someone had similar problem and can share their approach?

Comment: You should start with transforming your text data to its numerical representation (try bow, tf-idf or embeddings), reducing its dimension with some decomposition method (start with PCA and TSNE from sklearn) and visualizing it (with scatter plot) to estimate your "data shape". Then try applying different clusterization methods (again start with sklearn) until you get satisfactory result